# Angular: Issue performing put operation

Tags: angular

Following is my service in angular:

```
updateProducts(productForm, id) {
        const temp = {
            'description': productForm.description,
            'quality': productForm.quality
        };
        return this.httpObj.put(`${this.uri}/products/${id}`, JSON.stringify(temp), {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
    });
    }
```

In command terminal I see the request as PUT /products/NaN 200 118.602 ms - 4.Why it sends as NaN and not detecting ID?

backend:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a perfect example where TypeScript's typing would have probably saved you from passing a value that is Not A Number `NaN` for the `id` parameter. Type your inputs: `id: number` or `id: string`, whatever is appropriate, and see if the compiler will catch where you're not passing the correct type of value.

Comment: You also don't need to stringify the POST data if your endpoint is expecting JSON.

Comment: You don't need to set the `Content-Type` header for `application/json`. Angular does this by default.

Comment: @Brandon I am able to get the form data auto populated .now the thing is that data is not getting updated.  When I check in postman, the response I get is null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Postman doesn't make XHR requests unless you specifically add the `X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest` header. Add that to ensure your endpoint is receiving the correct type of request. After that, you'll need to add your service method code to your question. Otherwise, it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: service method is already added

Comment: No, the backend service.

Comment: @Brandon added pls check

Comment: Have you tried logging the `error`? Logging the `post`? Are you sure you need the forward slash in front of `/:id`? Are you using a parent router object in Express? There are a lot of things that could be wrong here.

Comment: removing '/ ' returns 404 and in console post  I see only null

Comment: Are you passing the correct data shape to the service? Are you using the json parser for Express? Again, lots of things can be wrong here. You'll need to add some more code from your Express application.

Comment: you mean that i should pass all the fields that I have in schema? I am able to post successfully but not put

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182368/discussion-between-brandon-and-mohammed-ajmal).